# Changing or adding attribute to span within a div

Tags: css

My display code could look like this:

```
<div class="displayApproved">
    <span class="bold">this is my text</span>
</div>
```

My `.displayApproved` has a `padding-top:8px;` to align to its neighbor element, and this works fine with non-bold content.

When there's a `<span 'class="bold"'>` inside, is there a way to adjust the padding on the div to 9px without creating a new class "displayApprovedBold" (several content pages would need changing)?  If there's an advanced CSS rule though that would adjust that div's padding *if* the div contained that bold span, then one change and I'm done.

Comment: I guess it would be simple enough to do in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can just do:

```
$('.displayApproved:has(.bold)').css('propery', 'value');
```